# Convert bash script to Windows

Tags: windows, bash, translate

I wrote the following script for Linux in order to detect drops in my network connection:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "### RUNNING ###"
echo "### $(date) ###" 

while true;do

    now=$(date +"%T")

    if [[ "$(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep '100.0% packet loss' )" != "" ]]; then
        echo "!!! KO ($now)" >> "log_connectivity_$(date +"%F")"
    else
        echo "OK ($now)" >> "log_connectivity_$(date +"%F")"
    fi
    sleep 5s
done
```

What it does is, within a loop, to ping 8.8.8.8 once and, if packet is lost it prints KO and the time and, otherwise, it prints OK and the time.

I would like to translate this bash script into a Windows script, but I have no idea. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: A Windows script using which language?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but as far as I know the most well-known language for scripts in Windows is batch, isn't it?

Comment: @KevinPadillaCañadas Which version of Windows? PowerShell would probably be a better target than batch

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mathias. I don't have any knowledge in Windows scripts, so if you suggest PowerShell rather than batch that's ok for me. Windows version would be 7 or/and 10.